# How to install CAL for RemoteFX on Server 2012 Standard

Tags: hyper-v, licensing, remote-desktop-services, cal, remote-desktop

I had to enable RemoteFX to be able to use a video card on my Server for Hyper-V 2012. I have ran out of the grace period for Remote Desktop Session Host Server. I have tired to install the CALs that I have purchased, however I don't get the option to, and I get the following error:

> The grace period for the Remote Desktop Session Host server has expired, but the RD Session Host server has not been configured with any license servers. Connections to the RD Session Host server will be denied unless a license server is configured for the RD Session Host server.

It says the solution is:

> Configure a license server for the Remote Desktop Session Host server. If you have an existing license server, specify that license server for the RD Session Host Server. Otherwise, install RD Licensing on a computer on your network and Configure RD Session Host Server to use it.

Here is a image as well.

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know how to configure for RemoteFX, and I can't find much info on it.

Comment: Have you done what it told you to do yet?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have now idea how, I have never done it before